# RP3+PlexTV and Smart Hub

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

first of all i would like to know if there really is anyone who has managed to connect the rapberry pi b3, which acts as a plex-tv server to a client such as a smart-tv or something similar.
I ask you this because so far I can connect to the plex media server, that is to the PI3, only from windows pc and android smartphone

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if we knew your TV make and model, and what you have tried to set up the TV, we could help more. I have installed the Plex app into the Smart Hub of my 2012 Samsung UE32ES5500 TV, with Plex Media Server running first on a Seagate GoFlex Home NAS, then a Raspberry Pi 3, and now a Raspberry Pi 4. I have to say I got bored with all the Plex bells and whistles and the changed Plex interface so I changed to Serviio DLNA server. Also I put a DLNA client on a Samsung Galaxy tablet and that worked connected to the Rpi 4 also and let me view media.

Answer (score 0):

I am very happy that someone gives me confirmation that it is possible to connect from SmartTv to the Raspberry PI3. My TV is a Samsung UE43NU7190.but I also encounter the same problem on other Smart devices, such as the blu ray player.  No any issue instead from client in Win device and Android phone.